# How to feature detect microsoft edge eye/reveal icon availability on input type=password

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge, shadow-dom

The user requirement (believe it or not) is on input type="password" fields to use the browser (Edge only) default "reveal" icon where available and otherwise use my bespoke solution.

I believe that MS uses shadow DOM to implement the eye image and even if that DOM is hidden I also believe there are ways of interrogating it.

My requirement id to feature detect the "reveal" functionality without browser sniffing.

How can I search the DOM on DOMContentLoaded to see the Eye?

Please help!

Comment: I don't think you *can* detect the "eye" - it's a browser feature. Why not just find `type="password"` fields, flip them to `type="text"` and have a button to flip them back?

Comment: Because, as previously stated in user requirements, they wand the browser "eye" where available. If not the bespoke version. Someone who know how to interrogat shadow dom should be able to help?

Comment: Only user generated shadowRoots can be "open" and accessed. Browser generated shadowRoots are "closed" by default.

Comment: But IIRC the "closed" check can be defeated

Comment: Aside from browser sniffing, I don't think there's another way to detect the "eye". Edge browser doesn't expose it for detecting. If you want this feature can be detected in Edge, you can provide your feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge.